# Coworkers resent added work, to help in my office

Tags: professionalism, communication

I have six coworkers who are required by the director to assist me a half a day once a week, two at a time, every Wednesday. This takes them from their own offices, which is an inconvenience for them and their own responsibilities. However this is out of my control.

Unfortunately their unhappiness is beginning reflect in the quality of the work done. This produces more work for me, as their help becomes a hinderance, and it causes dissatisfaction for both our customers and the company that we are in partnership with. It is pretty clear that they resent being take way from their own work to be in my office.

I am lost on how to handle this? Any suggestions would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: We need more info on what they are being taken away from and in order to do what.... and unless you are wasting their time, this is mostly something the director has to solve by clearly articulating why your task is currently a high priority.

Comment: Each person has their own office and specialty. Apparently this resentment started before I was hired to open this new office and service. The coworkers are being inconvenienced from thier normal work. It has been told to me by some of them that they do not want to be use to assist my office, that they are too busy.

Comment: Voting to close as "Unclear what you're asking" because the OP did not say why _six present coworkers are required by the director to assist me a half a day once a week_. The reason why they are required to do so can help to answer the question if the question is answerable.

Comment: On Wednesdays my usual one man office provides two separate services to the public. These services are scheduled by the partnership company. It is impossible for one person to handle this alone. This arrangement was set before the office was even opened and me being hired.

Answer (score 5):

They are not being evaluated on how good a job they are doing working for you. Have their manager tell them that your evaluation of them will count as part of their salary review and you should see a little more alacrity.

The problem is that they don't see you as their boss and that there is no downside to them about having an attitude that sucks.

Change the expectations and you'll change the attitude.

Answer (score 0):

Are you senior to them at all or are they the exact same level as you?

I’m assuming that they are the same level.  If at all possible, try to return the favour in some way.  Maybe on a quieter day for you, you could assist at least some of them?  Also, if you have an otherwise good relationship with them, you could talk to them about it and sympathise with the fact that it’s taking away from their own work (not apologise, but sympathise).  They’re less likely to screw up for you if they consider you a friend.  I wouldn’t say to them that they have already been doing a bad job, you’re just trying to sweeten them up at this stage.  Then, if the problem continues, you can say to them as a friend that they need to improve the quality of their work.

Comment: Offices are not attached. This is an office that is governed by appointsments scheduled in 15 minute internals. It is impossible for me to leave and work in another part other building. However on my own time I do assist coworkers when asked or offered.